# Merging a branch on a not updated master

Tags: git, error-handling, merge

**Issue**

I merged a branch in a master not updated at last commit.

**What I do**

I merged a branch in master

```
git merged BRANCHNAME
```

Conflicts

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

git commit -a -m "Resolved conflicts while merging email-fix branch"
```

Then I tried to push all to origin master, but it says:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

- a `git pull --rebase`, in order to replay your merge on top of an up-to-date master branch
- then a `git push` (which should go smoothly)

The other alternative would be to force the push, which would mean loosing the recent history on the remote master: not a very good idea.

Both alternatives are presented in the [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#Why_is_my_push_rejected_with_a_non-fast_forward_error.3F), although only a simple `git pull` is advocated.
The [`git push` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) mentions the `git pull --rebase`:

> For example, suppose you and somebody else started at the same commit `X`, and you built a history leading to commit `B` while the other person built a history leading to commit `A`. The history looks like this:

```
      B
     /
 ---X---A
```

> Alternatively, you can rebase your change between `X` and `B` on top of `A`, with "`git pull --rebase`", and push the result back. The rebase will create a new commit `D` that builds the change between `X` and `B` on top of `A`.

```
      B   D
     /   /
 ---X---A
```

> Again, updating `A` with this commit will fast-forward and your push will be accepted.